# Non www to www redirection in node server not working properly

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I have to following code to redirect non www requests to www on Node server :

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
 if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) === null ) res.redirect('https://www.' + 
 req.headers.host + req.url, 301);
 else next();
});
```

But if the user enters foo.com, it's not redirected to www.foo.com. Instead if foo.com is refreshed, then it's being redirected to www.foo.com

I've tried [ForceDomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-force-domain) as well but the problem exists. Is there anything that am I doing wrong ?

Following is the whole code :

```
var express=require('express');
var httpsRedirect = require('express-https-redirect');
path=require('path');
bodyParser=require('body-parser');
cors=require('cors');
passport=require('passport');
mongoose=require('mongoose');
config=require('./config/database');
app=express();
app.use('/', httpsRedirect());
port=3700;
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require('./config/passport')(passport);
var users=require('./routes/users');
admin=require('./routes/admin');
app.use('/users',users);
app.use('/admin',admin);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
app.listen(port,function(){console.log('Server logged on '+port)});
mongoose.connect(config.database);
mongoose.connection.on('connected',function(){
});
mongoose.connection.on('error',function(a){
 a&&console.log('Error'+a)
});
// Forcedomain to www

app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) === null ) res.redirect('https://www.' + req.headers.host + req.url, 301);
  else next();
});

app.get('*',function(a,b){
b.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'))
});
```

Comment: As a side note: do you have express running behind nginx or anything? I'd recommend doing it via that rather than via express

Comment: Also forceDomain should work fine. I'd be interested to see your whole code as it seems like it may be a red herring

Comment: @MattFletcher I just added all the code as you have asked. Please take a look, Thank you.

Comment: @MattFletcher I'm running it on apache on AWS Linux

Comment: Tried changing `app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {` to `app.use(function(req, res, next) {` ?

Comment: @MattFletcher I did but it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what I'm doing wrong. I was already using 'express-https-redirect' to redirect from http to https and then trying to redirect non www to www. Apparently, I have to do both at the same time. So I removed express-https-redirect and used [ForceDomain](https://github.com/thenativeweb/forcedomain) to redirect to https and www version as well. Now it works.